# TYPO3 FAL Append file (TYPO3 11 LTS)

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

What is the best practice to create or append a file in TYPO3 using a ResourceStorage Folder object?

Or how to retrieve the absolute path of a file/folder from the ResourceStorage object

```
$resourceFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ResourceFactory::class);
$defaultStorage = $resourceFactory->getDefaultStorage();
$defaultStorage->getFolder('_temp_');
$filePath = ''; // getPublicPath does not get the absolute path and no alternatives are found.

if ($filestream = fopen($filePath, 'a')) {
    // append file
    fwrite($filestream, 'test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the public path into TYPO3's

```
PathUtility::getAbsoluteWebPath();
```

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/ExamplesFileFolder.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no simple way to open an existing File to append something. You could use `File::getContents()` to get the content of the file, append your text and use `File::setContents()` to set the appended content. However this isn't very efficient.

If you're sure it's always a local Storage you could use `File::getForLocalProcessing(false)`, which returns the path of the file. But the parameter is meant to say if it should be writable, so if it's `false` you should not write anything to the file. It would work, though there might be unforeseen consequences.

For example:

```php
$resourceFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ResourceFactory::class);
$defaultStorage = $resourceFactory->getDefaultStorage();
$tempFolder = $defaultStorage->getFolder('_temp_');

$fileName = 'myFile.txt';
$file = $tempFolder->getFile($fileName);
if ($file === null) {
    $file = $tempFolder->createFile($fileName);
}
$filePath = $file->getForLocalProcessing(false);

if ($filestream = fopen($filePath, 'a')) {
    // append file
    fwrite($filestream, 'test');
}
```

You could also use `File::getForLocalProcessing()` (without a parameter, as it's `true` by default). This will create a copy of the file and return the path for the copy. Then you can append to that and when you're done, override the original file with the copy. This is less efficient, but more safe.

For example:

```php
$resourceFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ResourceFactory::class);
$defaultStorage = $resourceFactory->getDefaultStorage();
$tempFolder = $defaultStorage->getFolder('_temp_');

$fileName = 'myFile.txt';
$file = $tempFolder->getFile($fileName);
if ($file === null) {
    $file = $tempFolder->createFile($fileName);
}
$filePath = $file->getForLocalProcessing();

if ($filestream = fopen($filePath, 'a')) {
    // append file
    fwrite($filestream, 'test');
}
$tempFolder->addFile($filePath, $fileName, DuplicationBehavior::REPLACE);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to get a `File` object:

- If you know the file's storage (e.g. `1` = default storage), name (e.g. `foo.txt`) and path (e.g. `_temp_`):

```php
$resourceFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ResourceFactory::class);
$file = $resourceFactory->getFileObjectFromCombinedIdentifier('1:/_temp_/foo.txt');
```

- If you know the file's UID:

```php
$resourceFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ResourceFactory::class);
$file = $resourceFactory->getFileObject(4);
```

- If you want to get the folder first (and you know the filename):

```php
$resourceFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ResourceFactory::class);
$defaultStorage = $resourceFactory->getDefaultStorage();
$folder = $defaultStorage->getFolder('_temp_');
$file = $folder->getFile('foo.txt');
```

And to use the file with `fopen` / `fwrite`, you need the local path (e.g. `/var/www/html/your-project/private/fileadmin/user_upload/_temp_/foo.txt`):

```php
$filePath = $file->getForLocalProcessing(false);
```

If you want to set file contents "the TYPO3 way", you could use:

```php
$file->setContents('your new file contents');
```

As long as I know, there is no way to append contents directly, so you would have to use:

```php
$file->setContents($file->getContents() . 'your new appended file contents');
```